# Iframe form submit data to Window URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

Suppose I type a URL in browser (http://localhost:8080/Proj/page) and I get a page where I have menu and an iframe. on click of menu I am doing an ajax request to the server by posting some data and getting an HTML document as response.
I am manually updating the HTML document into iframe using javascript. {Reason behind this the URL has a query parameter and I want to POST it to the server and not GET,thus I am not changing iframe src}

Ex:

```
<a href="#" onClick="frameopen('helloWOrld.html?a=bc&d=ef')">menu</a>;
function frameopen(url) {
    var dataToSend = getQueryParameterFrmUrl(url);//got data in form of Object
    var urlWithoutQUeryParam = getUrlWithoutQueryParam(url);//got url without query parameter
    positionThrobber("section16_contentframe");//add the throbber
    //perform POST using ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: urlWithoutQUeryParam,
        data: dataToSend,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (serverResponse) {
            //server response came write this to iframe
            removeThrobber();
            var ifrm = document.getElementById('contentframe');
            ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
            ifrm.document.open();
            ifrm.document.write(serverResponse);//server response written
            ifrm.document.close();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            removeThrobber();
            alert("Ajax Request Failed!Text Status:" + textStatus + ",errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
        }

    });

}
```

Now the iframe is populated from server response and it contains a form.

```
<iframe src="">
<html><body>
<form name="inboxSearchForm" id="inboxSearchForm" commandName="userQueueFilter" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/inbox/search" method="post">
<a href="#" id="nextPage" onclick="pageJump(document.getElementById('pageNum').value,'up') ">Next ></a>
</form>
</body></html>
</iframe>
```

There is a link(called Next) inside iframe which  submit form using javascript

```
document.getElementById('inboxSearchForm').submit();
```

THE problem is when I click on link Next..the iframe is loaded with URL content `(http://localhost:8080/Proj/page` ie iframe now store entire page ie menu and iframe and it is recursive..can anyone tell me what could be the reason..
I want iframe to be refreshed from URL `/inbox/search` and not from the URL in the browser..This behaviours is not getting reflected in IE facing issue in mozilla :(

Comment: Not possible the way u want...

Comment: Means didint get you..what is the concern? why not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, IFrame page will never be able to contact the mainpage.

**Suggestion:**
Dont use Iframe for this purpose. If u want to get some content from other page use [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of jquery

But in your case i suggest you to make the form using a `div` rather iframe. The code may look same with some minor changes.